# is it some method(s) to replace it with method 'live' in jquery 10+?

Tags: jquery

i used this code to show a upload image dialog box to user it works on jquery-1.8.x.min
but when i upgrade it to jquery-1.10.2.min it gaves me this error:

```
0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't 
support property or method 'live'
```

i searched on Google and found .live has been removed from jquery-1.9+
what is this means and how can i handle it?

```
$(function () {

$("#UploadDialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false, width: 400,  modal: true, show: {
        effect: "blind",
        duration: 500
    },
    hide: {
        effect: "explode",
        duration: 1000
    },
    buttons: {

        Cancel: function () { $(this).dialog("close"); }
    }
});


$("#ppic").click(function () {
   $("#UploadDialog").html("")
     .dialog("option", "title", "upload file").attr('class', 'orderwaiting')
     .load("/ShowUploadDialog", function (){$("#UploadDialog").dialog("open");});
    });
});
```

on my html:

```
<img id="ppic" src="/userpic.png" alt="abc" />
<div id="UploadDialog" class="hidden_elem"></div>
```

Comment: you mean `.on` method ?

Comment: `live()` was removed in jQuery 1.9. Look up `on()`

Comment: None of the jQuery you posted even uses `.live()`.

Comment: @ j08691 then why IE 11 gives me this error?

Comment: @motevallizadeh because you're using .live somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

include jquery.migrate.js in your source code
or
you can use on().

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a method [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/), try it.

```
$( "#dataTable tbody tr" ).on( "click", function() {
    alert( $( this ).text() );
});
/* A delegated-events approach attaches an event handler to only one element, the tbody, and the event only needs to bubble up one level (from the clicked tr to tbody):*/
$( "#dataTable tbody" ).on( "click", "tr", function() {
    alert( $( this ).text() );
});
```